# How do I scrape the title of a page in Racket?

Tags: web-scraping, scheme, html-parsing, racket

I got to the point of obtaining the html of the page with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env racket
#lang racket/base

(require net/url racket/port)
(require (planet neil/html-parsing:3:0))

(define p (get-pure-port (string->url "https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Web_scraping")))
(define my-html (port->string p))
(close-input-port p)
```

How do I get the title, i.e. the text inside of `<title>` tag,  from `my-html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer working with XML tooling over HTML, or in Racket (And scheme in general), [sxml](https://docs.racket-lang.org/sxml-intro/index.html). That lets you use [XPath-like queries](https://docs.racket-lang.org/sxml/sxpath.html) to easily extract data from the document. Luckily, it's simple to parse HTML into a sxml expression:

```lisp
#!/usr/bin/env racket
#lang racket
(require html-parsing)
(require sxml/sxpath)

(define my-html "<!doctype html><html><head><title>Title text here</title></head><body><p>a paragraph of text</p></body></html>")
(define document (html->xexp my-html))
; Returns a list of strings
(display-lines ((sxpath "/html/head/title/text()") document))
```

or in your case

```lisp
(define document (call/input-url (string->url "https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Web_scraping")
                                 get-pure-port html->xexp))
```

(`html->xexp` takes either a string holding a HTML document or an input port)

The interesting bit is `sexp`, which takes an SXPath string and returns a new procedure that when called in turn with a sxml argument, returns a list of all matches. If you're going to be looking for the same thing repeatedly, it's worth defining a new function instead of using a temporary:

```lisp
(define get-title-text (sxpath "/html/head/title/text()"))
```

---

The `html-parsing` and `sxml` packages should be installed via the DrRacket package manager or from the command line with `raco pkg install html-parsing sxml`, whichever you prefer.

Comment: There's also a core [`html`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/html/index.html) library that offers HTML4 parsing, but its documentation suggests using `html-parsing` instead since the latter is more flexible in what it accepts.

Comment: Thanks. I converted the list of all matches with `string-join` as I need to process the title further.

Comment: That also neatly handles the case of no title tag being present since an empty list joins into an empty string.